# React Native Android: Bouncing Scroll View

Tags: android, react-native, scrollview

I know the regular scrollview on Android doesn't bounce, but I want this functionality. I am trying to use the package [SpringScrollView](https://bolan9999.github.io/react-native-spring-scrollview/#/en/V2/Usage), but when I replace my `<ScrollView>` components with `<SpringScrollView>` I receive the error

```
Requiring unknown module "94". If you are sure the module exists, try restarting Metro. You may also want to run 'yarn' or 'npm install'.
```

I don't really what Metro is, but if I just shut down the app, and rerun it using `yarn install` I get the same error

---

**Update**

I run into problems with the [installation instructions in the documentation](https://bolan9999.github.io/react-native-spring-scrollview/#/en/V2/GettingStart) when I arrive at the part for MainApplication.java. The documentation specifies to modify my getPackages() function to be

```
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
      new MainReactPackage(),
      new SpringScrollViewPackage()
  );
}
```

My getPackages function for my MainApplication.java looked a little bit different

```
    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      packages.add(
        new ModuleRegistryAdapter(mModuleRegistryProvider)
      );
      return packages;
    }
```

So I tried to modify it to be

```
    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      packages.add(
        new ModuleRegistryAdapter(mModuleRegistryProvider)
      );
      packages.add(new SpringScrollViewPackage());
      return packages;
    }
```

But when I do this, I receive this error when I build

```
error: cannot find symbol
      packages.add(new SpringScrollViewPackage());
                       ^
  symbol: class SpringScrollViewPackage
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

I tried installing a version that was 0.* also, because it looks like the fancy instructions are only for the 2.* versions, but when I do that and use a SpringScrollView I get an error like

```
"You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports"
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting the entire node_modules and then run yarn install?

Comment: @VinayRevankar Doing that right now. It takes a while on my computer

Comment: While you do that let me know the version of react-native the app uses

Comment: ~16.9.0, at least that's what's listed under my dependencies in my package.json file

Comment: @VinayRevankar Same error after removing node_modules and running `yarn install`

Comment: Make sure you have properly installed react-native-spring-scrollview, check android instructions. restart the package manager and try

Comment: Hope you have followed instructions for the SpringScrollView https://bolan9999.github.io/react-native-spring-scrollview/#/en/V2/GettingStart. If so can try running command  ./gradlew clean in android directory

Comment: @Wolverine Well I tried to(https://bolan9999.github.io/react-native-spring-scrollview/#/en/V2/GettingStart) I ran into problems `Make sure new SpringScrollViewPackage() is in your MainApplication.java`. The code under there doesn't really match anything in my MainApplication.java file, so I couldn't find out the right place to put it

Comment: @VinayRevankar I tried, my getPackages() function looks like this, so I didn't really know how to add the stuff that they mention `    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      packages.add(new ModuleRegistryAdapter(mModuleRegistryProvider));
      return packages;
    }`

Comment: Right click on getPackages() and click on goto implementations. It will open up the PackageList.java file. Here you need to make the changes

Comment: @VinayRevankar I posted an update which explains the trouble I'm having with the installation. When I right click getPackages, the option for implementations is greyed out under goto

Comment: @Sam please include all the contents of `package.json` into your question.

Answer (score 1):

**Above the function** `getPackages` you posted :

```
 @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      packages.add(
        new ModuleRegistryAdapter(mModuleRegistryProvider)
      );
      return packages;
 }
```

You might see a new object `ReactModuleRegistryProvider` be created.
Try adding you package there.

````
private final ReactModuleRegistryProvider mModuleRegistryProvider = new ReactModuleRegistryProvider(Arrays.<Package>asList(
    new SpringScrollViewPackage(),  // add this line there
), Arrays.<SingletonModule>asList());```
````

Answer (score 0):

MetroBundler bundles the App for you, so that you can run/debug it.
It might be, that there are some old cache files or outdated files around.

Mostly it's not easy to say what exactly the issue with metro, but in my opinion following steps helping very often:

(Notice, this is for Linux users... if you use Windows, replace the singe commands inside by your os-command)

Add those lines to your *package.json* - scripts-Section to be able to run it whenever you like:

```
"kill_MetroBundler": "lsof -i :8081 | grep node | awk '{print $2}'| head -1 | xargs kill",
"clean-start": "rm -rf ./node_modules && yarn install && watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-map-react-native-packager-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*",
```

So I recommend first to search and kill all metroBundler processes. My above command search with `lsof` for Services running on Port 8081, and after piping to some processes (to get the needed Program-Name) it executed a `kill` for it, to force the Process to close.

After that, you also should run `clean-start` wich remove your `node_module` directory, reinstall the modules, kill all watchmen and chached bundler & packager processes.

Sometimes, in really hard cases, this also not work.
Here I've figured out, that it might be needed to re-create the bundler-file for Android:

```
"RN_Bundle": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --reset-cache --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/build/generated/res/react/release",
```

If you use this command, I recommend this order:

1. kill_MetroBundler
2. clean-start
3. RN_Bundle

It might be, that you have to adjust the Commands a bit for your need, but for me, those one did the job for me at least, most of the time.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You have not "linked" the library to the android project. Unlike real JVM libraries, which are added to the project's path automatically by the dependency manager, react-native "libraries" copypaste whole android subprojects into node_modules, which then need to be added to the android app's settings.gradle and build.gradle. Into your project, there should be an android/settings.gradle, where you need to add something like

```
include ':SpringScrollView'
project(':SpringScrollView').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../src/base/SpringScrollView/android')
```

Then, in the android/app/build.gradle file, something like:

```
implementation project(':SpringScrollView')
```

Then the "library" will be added to the path and the classes would be there (This assumes SpringScrollView is the library's folder name inside node_modules).

good luck and patience. You'll need it with RN.